# Agricola board game score card modelling in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a small webapp in Rails that simulates a score card for the board game [Agricola](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/agricola.htm).

**The question is: What/How is the best (read: proper) way to model the score card in Rails?**

Currently, I have a `ScoreCard` model which columns are the 'categories' that counts toward the final score. It's something like:

```
class ScoreCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :field_tile,
            :pasture,
            :grain,
            :vegetable,
            :sheep,
            :wild_boar,
            :cattle,
            :unused_space,
            :fenced_stable,
            :clay_room,
            :stone_room,
            :family_member,
            :victory_point,
            :bonus_point,
            :numericality => true
end
```

The scoring mechanism is described [in this game manual](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/agricola/Agricola_Rules.pdf) (see the 'Scoring' section on page 8). Here's a snippet from the manual:

> Fields: All field tiles that are on
>   the player’s farmyard are scored,
>   regardless of whether they are
>   currently fallow or are sown. A player
>   with 0 or 1 fields loses 1 point. Each
>   field after the first scores 1 point,
>   up to a maximum of 4 points for 5 or
>   more fields. Players score -1/1/2/3/4
>   points for 0-1/2/3/4/5+ fields.
>
> Pastures: Points are awarded for
>   fenced areas (“Pastures”), not for the
>   number of farmyard spaces that are
>   fenced in (“Pasture spaces”). The size
>   of the individual pastures is
>   irrelevant. A player with no pastures
>   loses 1 point. Each pasture scores 1
>   point, up to a maximum of 4 points for
>   4 or more pastures. Players score
>   -1/1/2/3/4 points for 0/1/2/3/4+ pastures.

Since each 'category' (pasture, grain, etc) has different scoring mechanism, I defined some private methods that returns the final score of each 'category':

```
private
  def calculate_field_tiles_score
    case field_tile
      when 0..1 then -1
      when 2..4 then field_tile - 1
      else 4
    end 
  end

  def calculate_pasture_score
    # return proper score
  end
```

I also have a (public) `calculate` method in the model which calculates the final score:

```
def calculate
  calculate_field_tiles_score +
  calculate_pasture_score +
  # ... other scores
end
```

Is this a good approach? I'm not sure what the proper way of modelling it, but it doesn't 'feel right'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for something along the lines of:

```
class Scorer
  def initialize(farmyard); @farmyard=farmyard; end
end

class FieldTilesScorer < Scorer
  def score
    case @farmyard.field_tile 
      #etc
    end
  end
end

class PasturesScorer < Scorer
   def score
     #return proper score
   end
end
```

and so on. Then when I want to score a farmyard, I'd do:

```
[FieldTilesScorer, PastureScorer, ...].
  map{|s| s.new(@farmyard).score}.
  inject(0){|m,r| m+r}
```

This way you're modelling each category as its own class, and it's easy to add rules which depend on any combination of state in the farmyard.

Comment: I don't quite get what your second snippet of code (the one with `map` and `inject`) does. Can you please briefly explain?

Comment: The `map` takes each scorer and calls it for the `@farmyard` generating a list of individualized scores. The `inject` iterates through that score list and sums them by calling the block with the previous result (starting at 0) and the current item in the list giving a total score.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Take the score given by each scorer, then add them. Simple as that, really :-)